# SQL query won't get the data

Tags: sql

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with this SQL

```
SELECT 
    ctransno, cplateno, ctransfrm, ctransto, dtransdate 
FROM 
    VTRANSFERS 
WHERE 
    dtransdate = '1/28/2013' 
ORDER BY 
    dtransdate DESC`
```

This SQL runs but it won't retrieve the data, `dtransdate` is of `DATETIME` type

Comment: what's data type of column dtransdate?

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? `DB2`? etc..

Comment: If you specify **dates as strings** in SQL Server, you should **always** use a safe format - e.g. `YYYYMMDD` which is not depedent on any language and/or regional settings in your SQL Server installation!

Comment: remove WHERE dtransdate = '1/28/2013' and post some data, just focus on datetime format how it saves on your table? I think it's like (yyyy-mm-dd) so if true you have to change your condition to (dtransdate = '2013-28-1')

Comment: Also depending on your data there may not be any records with a transaction date of tomorrow yet.

Answer (score 2):

When you have already specified that the date, dtransdate = '1/28/2013'

Then how can you expect a descending sort on the same dates? Think over your query first before posting.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using sql server then use `DateDiff` function.

```
SELECT ctransno,cplateno,ctransfrm,ctransto,dtransdate
FROM VTRANSFERS WHERE DATEDIFF(dd,dtransdate ,'1/28/2013')=0 
ORDER BY dtransdate DESC
```